# Find equivalent value on different ranges

Tags: math

So...
I've been banging my head on the wall over this problem for a few days now, but still couldn't find a solution.

I have two ranges of numbers

A -> B

C -> D

A given number (x) is on the A -> B range.

I need to find it's equivalent in the C -> D range.

eg:

A -> B = (2 -> 4)

C -> D = (-148 -> -50)

x = 2.3

What is the equivalent value on the (-148 -> -50) range?

Comment: Maybe you should use https://math.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about maths.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about [math.se] instead of programming or software development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your requirements are a bit loose, but I would be tempted to believe you want to find an affine transformation from the interval `[2;4]` to `[-148;-50]`.

Calling `f(x) = a.x + b` this transformation, you have:

```
f(2) = 2.a + b = -148
f(4) = 4.a + b = -50

=> 2.f(2) = 4.a + 2.b = -296
=> 2.f(2) - f(4) = b = -246
=> a = (-148 - b)/2 = 49

=> f(x) = 49.x - 246
```

So the point you are looking for would be `f(2.3) = -133.3`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `((X - A) * (D - C) / (B - A)) + C`.

Size of first range is: `B - A`

Size of second range is: `D - C`

Ratio between `(X - A)` and `(Y - C)` should be proportional to that of `(B - A)` and `(D - C)`.